# leave an inch by inch margin -- top right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, margins

I'm doing a very plain TeX file. I'm using it to put a lot of notes onto a page; however, it's required that I have about an inch by inch box of margin on the top right of the very first place (my margins are otherwise much smaller on all sides).

How can I accomplish this? Ideally, it stays that way -- only on the first page -- and does not change when I make changes to other parts of the file / edits in word count and such.

Here's some code:

```
\documentclass[8pt, letter, twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[bottom=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  
\begin{document}
Name and stuff
\section{something}
Long long sprawling thing that goes on for about 10 pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just add a gap at the top of the first text area until the margin plus gap totals 1 in.  gap=`-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep` and no header on first page.

Comment: I'd like it just to be an inch by inch square in the top right @JohnKormylo . Also, that command doesn't work. `\topmargin \headheight` works, but adds a huge amount at the top.

Comment: would you like to share your code as a minimal example so that it can be suitably edited

Comment: done @jsbibra  .

Comment: "Plain TeX" also means "not LaTeX."  The MWE cleared that up.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier of overlap margins than set them, especially non rectangular ones.  This uses the overlay option of tikzpicture
(run twice).

```
\documentclass[8pt, letter, twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[bottom=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
  
\begin{document}
Name and stuff
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]% anywhere on the first page
  \draw (current page.north east) rectangle ++(-1in,-1in);
  \path (current page.north east) ++(-0.5in,-0.5in)
    node{\parbox{0.9in}{\centering this is a test}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{something}
Long long sprawling thing that goes on for about 10 pages
\end{document}
```

---

This version uses LaTeX hooks.

```
\documentclass[8pt, letter, twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[bottom=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put (\dimexpr \paperwidth-1in\relax,-0.5in) {%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr 1in-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax
  \fbox{\parbox[c][\dimen0][c]{\dimen0}{\centering
    this is a test}}}}
    
\begin{document}
Name and stuff

\section{something}
Long long sprawling thing that goes on for about 10 pages
\end{document}
```

---

This uses flowfram to create the irregular margin.  The problem with frowfram is that a paragraph will not change widths at the border between two frames.

```
\documentclass[8pt, letter, twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[bottom=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  
\usepackage{flowfram}
\newflowframe[1]{\dimexpr \textwidth+0.5cm-1in}% width
  {\dimexpr 1in-0.5cm}% height
  {0pt}% left edge
  {\dimexpr \textheight+0.5cm-1in}% bottom
\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth}% width
  {\dimexpr \textheight+0.5cm-1in}% height
  {0pt}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}% random text
    
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{something}
Long long sprawling thing that goes on for about 10 pages

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Both create a box in top right corner. The issue is there is text in that top right corner, and it is overlapped by the box. It should just be a plain whitespace up there.