Shape around empty box in every page
I want to leave an empty box of fixed dimensions in the upper right corner of every page.
Something of the kind that you obtain with the following code:
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{10pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=124mm,height=120mm,paperwidth=222mm,width=212mm,left=5mm,top=2.5mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{If the title is very long, I want it to respect the shape}
\parshape 3 0mm 150mm 0mm 150mm 0mm 150mm
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage

\parshape 3 0mm 150mm 0mm 150mm 0mm 150mm
Consider the first paragraph made by one line only: then I don't get any shape

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}

Problems with this code:

it applies only to the first page: it should apply to every page of the document (without me saying so as I do in pag. 3);
if the first paragraph is just one line (see pag. 3), \parshape does not apply to the second one, so the second paragraph floods into the shape: I need the box to be empty regardless of the number of paragraphs it spans;
it doesn't apply to the title: I need the box empty everywhere;
I do not understand why it shapes all the lines in the first paragraphs, despite I told \parshape to shape only the first 3.

Edit: if possible, it would be great to draw a frame around the box which is to be empty.

this is very tricky, bordering on impossible, in tex as linebreaking and page breaking are asynchronous, the paragraphs are broken into lines without knowledge of the page breaking, so the parshape can not adapt to a mid-paragraph page break.

for your question 4, the last \parshapeline is repeated until end of paragraph so you want to use 4 not 3 and specify a full width line for lines from line 4

@DavidCarlisle I see. It looks like not everything is possible in latex, after all...   :(

it can be done, taking page break information from the previous run and adjusting the parshape, but that then changes all later page breaks so it may take many runs to stabilize even after the final edit. If you use luatex there are more possibilities as you can (in principle) grab the paragraph before linebreaking and do trial runs of each paragraph within the same latex run. It's not easy in any case.

Depending on your document length, this may be done manually, on a page-by-page basis.

flowfram can help if you are prepared to do it manually as @Werner suggests. That is, it can do it semi-automatically, but it really needs interventions to manually break the text for almost every box. Then you can divide your page into 3 frames: 2 'flow' frames and 1 static. Testing suggests it will do fine with the chapter titles provided they fit into a single frame. (I did not test with titlesec!)

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709012/leave-an-inch-by-inch-margin-top-right

I cut out some of the code from the MWE but the below prints a box in the top-right corner of every page using tikz. See also How do I put (or not) something on every page independently of headers and footers?.
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Add the filled box to every page
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[black] ([shift={(-0.5,-0.5)}]current page.north east) rectangle +(-0.25,0.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

% Your content goes here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ultricies metus nec dolor ultrices, in vehicula dolor fermentum.

\newpage

The second page

\end{document}


this doesn't answer the question, the OP wants the shape to cut into the paragraph text on each page.

@DavidCarlisle: you are right: this just answer the added point in the edit at the end. And even there, is more of a workaround because it is just a figure, unrelated to the box

Ok, I've reread the question a couple of times but I had to run the MWE to understand the question. I'd say that the goal is to "reserve space for an empty box that the text body wraps around but the box can be moved by titles and section header, etc." or similar.
